# Kotlin-DataBinding-Error: Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-databinding

How can I solve this problem. I can't make this data binding work, I have tried everything.
Build.gradle(module app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fusion.alen.ask"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

I tried adding kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$compiler_version" but it gives me an error.
Build.gradle(Module project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext{
        kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
        compiler_version = '3.2.1'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This is my profile_fragment.xml, I have followed documentation instructions

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.alen.ask.UserModel.User" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_box"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/primaryColor"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/qff_box"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:baselineAligned="false">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/questions_number"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        **android:text="@{user.questionsNum}"************
                        tools:text="0" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/followers_number"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        **android:text="@{user.followersNum}"************
                        tools:text="0" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/following_number"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        **android:text="@{user.followingNum}"***********
                        tools:text="0" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/primaryDarkColor"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username_text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                **android:text="@{user.name}"**
                android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

My User data class:

```
data class User(val name: String,
                val email: String,
                val uid: String,
                val photo: String,
                val postsList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList(),
                val questionsNum: Int = 0,
                val followersNum: Int = 0,
                val followingNum: Int = 0
                )
```

This is inside ProfileFragmen class, in onCreateView method

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding = ProfileFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.user = user
}
```

That line binding.user = user gives me error: **Cannot access class 'UserModel.User'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies**
How can I solve this, I have followed instructions from DataBinding documentation and I don't think I have made any mistake. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, but it didn't work. I have tried adding those 'kapt' dependencies, didn't work.... 
File->ProjectStructure->Gradle version: 4.10.1, AndroidPluginVersion: 3.2.1, KotlinLanguageVersion: 1.2, KotlinPluginVersion: 1.2.71-release-Studio3.2-1

Thank you.

Answer (score 31):

Rename your folder UserModel to userModel then clean/rebuild your project. I had the same problem and the error disapeared when set my folder's first letter to lower case. In the future use camelCase for your folders name just like for variables. Upper case on the first letter is usually for classes.

Comment: it's ok. i dont think problem like that :D. thanks

Comment: I was checking on dependencies and did invalidate cache and restart. Thanks for this

Answer (score 23):

The reason is because one of your package name begins with Capital.

The **class name** which uses databinding should begin with **capital**, and **package name** should start with **lower case**. [This is not just for databinding, this is the convention followed commonly]

[Internally when dataBinding generates bindingImplementation for your xml, it parses your package name to identify the class,
 if the package name begins with capital it is not able to separate the Class name from the package name, and it throws an error.]

Comment: I also had same issue, It was a problem because I had First letter of my package name in Caps, I changed it to small nd it works. THanks

Answer (score 14):

Had the same issue, fixed it by changing build features in the `build.gradle` module from `viewBinding` to `dataBinding`

```
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding = true
}
```

Comment: In my case I needed both `viewBinding true` and `dataBinding true`

Answer (score 5):

Solution for **multi-module Gradle** projects if you build more than one app from the codebase:

The ViewBinding and DataBinding libraries have problems with its internal generated source sets while using many `Gradle module`s.

**Issue:**

You have 2 XML layout files which are named the same (like `content_main.xml`). Both are present in the `:first-app` module and the `:second-app` one in `layout` dirs. The IDE will render you red errors.

***But, the app will compile and launch properly.***

**Solution:**

Distinguish names for `XML` files - so the bindings will be generated as: `FirstAppContentMainBinding` (`first_app_content_main.xml`) and `SecondAppContentMainBinding` (`second_app_content_main.xml`)

Answer (score 0):

At file `profile_fragment.xml` try to replace this

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="user"
        type="com.alen.ask.UserModel.User" />
</data>
```

with this

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="user"
        type="com.alen.ask.User" />
</data>
```

and give us a feedback.

Comment: My User data class is inside UserModel folder so removing it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
<data class="ProfileBinding">
    <variable
        name="user"
        type="com.alen.ask.UserModel.User" />
</data>
```

use the above mentioned ProfileBinding class inside Fragment class to inflate

Answer (score 0):

Try to use binding.setVariable method.

Comment: Please notice suggestions should not be posted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing 'fusion' in your `variable` tag, although you have it in your `applicationId` in gradle.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still has this problem related to safe args just add this to your `build.gradle`

```
android {
...
sourceSets {
    main {
        kotlin {
            srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/navigation-args'
        }
    }
}
...
}
```

it works for me