# InteliJ desktop compose project compile issue

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I am making a desktop app using Kotlin compose(IntelliJ version 2021.2.1). My project is still running but I am getting these compile errors in the kotlin compose code.

"Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies"

Here are my project configurations [image: Made of the project]

[image: my gradle file]

[image]

[image]

As a solution, I removed cashe in .gradle and restart IDE with invalidating cashe but didn't work. and changed JDK versions and kotlin versions as well but still getting the same output.

Comment: check the answers of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571959/kotlin-databinding-error-check-your-module-classpath-for-missing-or-conflicting

Comment: have you tried updating IDE plugin? You need to go to settings->plugins->install or update "Compose Multiplatform IDE Support". Try creating a new project after that.

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov  yes I did but it didn't work for me. thanks

Comment: @PhilipDukhov yes but didn't help :( thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your project uses pretty outdated versions of both kotlin and Compose.

Check out that your [Compose Multiplatform IDE Support plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16541-compose-multiplatform-ide-support) is up to date, the latest version for today is `1.0.0-alpha4-build331`

Latest versions of plugins for `build.gradle.kts`:

```
kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.21"
id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.0.0-alpha3"
```

Comment: Finally I installed IntelliJ 2020.3 with Kotlin 1.4 with JDK 11 and it worked for me :) thanks for the response

Comment: This saved my day